# Apply results on each, keeps overriding

Tags: jquery, loops, each, color-thief

I am using color-thief js to get the color of each image inside a div.  I am trying to loop through each and retrieve colors. This works fine. In my console, it shows the colors for each image.

I have some extra code that converts the results, which are in RGB, to HEX.  This also works fine in the console.  My results are HEX colors for each image.

When I try to apply the HEX to a div, i always get the last color.

I understand what is going in, the loop keeps overriding itself, therefore returning the last color. I just don't know how to prevent this and on each loop apply the color to a div.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var color_thief = new ColorThief();

  $('.thumbnail-image-link img').each(function() {
    var dominant_color = color_thief.getPalette(this, 2);

    // Converts RGB to HEX
    function componentToHex(c) {
      var hex = c.toString(16);
      return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    }

    function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
      return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
    }

    var colorOne = rgbToHex(dominant_color[0][0], dominant_color[0][1], dominant_color[0][2]);
    console.log("Hex One " + colorOne);

    var colorTwo = rgbToHex(dominant_color[1][0], dominant_color[1][1], dominant_color[1][2]);
    console.log("HEX Two " + colorTwo);

    //This is where my issue is
    $(".section").css('background', colorOne);

  });
});
```

Edit: Added HTML Code.
Edit 2: Took out extra div to avoid confusion.
[image: HTML Code]

Basically, I need to add a background color to each .section as it loops.

```
Loop Start //depending how many images the for.each returns.
 -container -> value from loop 1 results
 -container -> value from loop 2 results
 -container -> value from loop 3 results
 -container -> value from loop 4 results
Loop End
```

Thanks again!

Comment: share your html code too

Comment: It looks like you're setting the `css()` on *every* `.mydiv` and `.myDiv2` element, instead of the ones related to the current `img` in the iteration. You need to use DOM traversal to select them instead. We can't show you exactly how without seeing the associated HTML, though.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the first iteration's `colorOne` to be assigned to the first `.section`, and the second iteration's `colorOne` to be assigned to the second `.section`, etc?

Comment: Exactly! While it loops, I would like colorOne to be assigned to the first .section, on next loop the results of colorOne to the second .section etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `$('.thumbnail-image-link img').each` loop, save the index of the current element you're iterating over by defining the first argument of the `each` callback. Then you can use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the correct `.section` element, and set its CSS:

```
$('.thumbnail-image-link img').each(function(i) {
```

and then

```
$(".section").eq(i).css('background', colorOne);
```

Comment: Awesome!  I read through the .eq docs.  A appreciate it. Also, if i wanted to get a second color from the pallet, just add another line: `$(".section").eq(i).css('background', colorTwo);`